# jQuery Creating Entire DOM Structures

Tags: jquery, dom

```
        /* TOP TABLE */
        var divTop = $('<div>', {
            className: "dynamicTableTop",
            html: '<p>' + options.name + '</p>'
        }).appendTo(obj);

        //Create  div
        var divAO = $('<div>', {
            className: "advancedOptions"
        }).appendTo(divTop);

        //Create Advanced Options link
        $('<a>', {
            href: "#",
            className: "linkAdvancedOptions",
            text: "Advanced Options",
            click: function () {
                $('.advancedOptionsPicker').slideToggle(300);
            }
        }).appendTo(divAO);

        $('<div>', {
            className: "advancedOptionsPicker"
        }).appendTo(divAO);

        var dynamicTable = $('<div>', {
            className: "dynamicTable"
        }).appendTo(obj);
```

So in the code above I'm creating an entire DOM structure. I create a div called divTop and one called divAO and then appendTo divTop. I create an anchor and then appendTo divAO.
This works real well. So my question is simply, is this how you guys would do it? Is this the best/fastest way?

Comment: Mark: Please take a moment to return to [your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/533853/mark#tabs-question-user), and accept an answer to each question where there was an answer that helped you solve the issue. You do this by clicking on the large checkmark to the left of your favorite answer. Thanks. :o)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, but if this structure will never change you might as well just write it in your HTML, no?

Comment: Can't everything is being built dynamically.

Comment: OK well then this is OK. I would in fact do it this way rather than as a big string, so that there is consistency where you define event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the reason you do it.

If what will be created can change a lot and depend on other factors I think it can be a good way as concatenation can get very ugly to debug.

Using the dom to build ensures some working structure.

But for elements that will never be dynamically designed, just created the same over and over, it is probably easier to just store it in a string, possibly with replacementmarkers.

I have used similar constructs myself.

And you should never use this for static HTML that is never changed.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an awnser to you question, but reading your question I was reminded of [this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly). It discusses how to efficiently use appendTo(). I imagine it could be interesting to you, especially if you plan on using it allot (as it appears)

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use *#* as your HREF; use a real link, and return false from your click event-handler. Also, if this is simply to power some GUI element, I highly recommend against using an A (anchor) tag, as anchor tags are meant for LINKS, not GUI controls. If you need a GUI control, use an input button (that's what they were made for!).
2. The selector *$('.advancedOptionsPicker')* would likely benefit from some context; e.g. something like *$('select.advancedOptionsPicker')* or *$('.advancedOptionsPicker', '#optionsPickerContainer')*.
3. You might want to look into [Document Fragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) when constructing & appending lots of HTML manually.