# Create a list in JQuery

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to create a List Object in jquery, I'm using the following code but it's not working, I found this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AeFMF/) so I wrote a similar thing.

```
function Node(left, right, content)
{
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.content = content;
}

var n1 = new Node('', n2, 'content content content');    
var n2 = new Node(n1, n2, 'content content content');
var n3 = new Node(n2, '', 'content content content');

console.log(box2);
```

Now, if i call `n1.right` it return undefined.
can help me please.

Comment: I removed the [tag:jquery] tag since this really has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I found some solution in Jquery, but it's not working also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595312/jquery-creating-entire-dom-structures

Comment: Well, you are passing `n2` to `new Node` before it has a value, hence it's `undefined`. You cannot pass the node to another node before it exists.

Comment: @FelixKling, how to fix it?

Comment: @T.Baba: I don't really see what the question you linked to has to do with the question you're asking. I *think* you're trying to create a linked list in JavaScript, while the other question has to do with manipulating the DOM.

Comment: var n1=....('', n2, 'content content content').. where is n2 here??

Comment: Set `n1.right = n2;` after you created `n2` (and `n1` obviously). Eventually you might want to add setters and getters to your instances, but that's out of scope here.

Comment: @T.Baba : You must put in efforts to learn how it is done. Asking everyone `show me the code` isn't gonna help you in any way. I see you are not interested in understanding what people people answering you have to say. All you are concerned about is `quick fix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `n2` to `new Node` before it has a value, hence it's `undefined`. You cannot pass the node to another node before it exists.

An easy fix would be to "link" the nodes after you created them:

```
function Node(content, left, right)
{
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.content = content;
}

var n1 = new Node('content content content');    
var n2 = new Node('content content content');
var n3 = new Node('content content content');

n1.right = n2;
n2.left = n1;
n2.right = n3;
n3.left = n2;
```

Though you'd probably want some getter and setter methods to properly handle insertions of new nodes into the list.

Learn more about how objects work: [MDN - Woking with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

---

This could be an XY problem though, in which case you'd have to explain what problem you are actually trying to solve. If you just want to create a list of objects, you can use an [array *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making use of `left` and `right` to link to the other Nodes, include all your Nodes in another Node, which would act as the list's container.

You can access the elements from the outer Node.

For example:

```
function Node(content) {
  this.nodes = [];
  this.content = content;
  this.addNode = function(node) {
    this.nodes.push(node);
  };
  this.changeContent = function(newContent) {
    this.content = newContent;
  };
}

var container = new Node();
container.addNode(new Node("Node 1"));
container.addNode(new Node("Node 2"));
container.addNode(new Node("Node 3"));

console.log(container);
```

**[As seen on Codepen](http://codepen.io/MadaraUchiha/pen/BhElK)**

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
var n1 = new Node('', n2, 'content content content');    
var n2 = new Node(n1, n2, 'content content content');
var n3 = new Node(n2, '', 'content content content');
```

When you are creating `n1` there is no `n2` object, so you inserting `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you ommitted some useful code here. What is the box2 object for example.

Anyways you tried to add n2 to n1 but it doesn't yet exist:

```
var n1 = new Node('', n2, 'content content content'); // n2 does not yet exist   
var n2 = new Node(n1, n2, 'content content content'); // n2 can't reference itself yet
var n3 = new Node(n2, '', 'content content content');
```

You should create a root node first or create a more sophisticated object pattern where you can add the connections to nodes once they have been created.

Comment: Felix has already given you the solution. This is very basic stuff so I'm not going to do it all for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14481491/775007

Answer (score 0):

```
function Node(left, right, content)
{
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.content = content;
}

var n1 = new Node('', null, 'content content content');    
var n2 = new Node(n1, n2, 'content content content');

n1.right=n2;

var n3 = new Node(n2, '', 'content content content');

console.log(n1.right);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make Node constructor update left/right nodes. So if current node has n2 as left, than n2 should have current node as right:

```
function Node(left, right, content)
{
    this.left = left;  
    this.right = right;
    this.content = content;
    if(left) {
       left.right = this;
    }
    if(right) {
       right.left = this;
    }
}

var n1 = new Node(null, null, 'content content content');    
var n2 = new Node(n1, null, 'content content content');
var n3 = new Node(n2, null, 'content content content');

console.log(n1.right.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said you can't assign the value until it's been created. You could do some lazy loading, but that sounds like it would complicate things for you. Try this:

```
function Node(content, prev, next) {
    var setPrev = function(node){
        var oldPrev = this.prev;
        this.prev = node;
        node.next = this;
        node.prev = oldPrev;
    }
    ,setNext = function(node){
        var oldNext = this.next;
        this.next = node;
        node.next = oldNext;
        node.prev = this;
    }
    return {
        'content': content,
        'prev': prev,
        'next': next,
        'setPrev': setPrev,
        'setNext': setNext
    }
}
n1 = new Node('content content content');    
n2 = new Node('content content content', n1);
n3 = new Node('content content content', n2);
n1.setNext(n2);
n2.setNext(n3);
```

It's also a great idea to encapsulate this into some sort of List object that can handle things like `appendNode`, `prependNode`, `insertAfter`, `insertBefore`, etc.